# Commas before “Or”

Tags: commas

I have a quick question about how to interpret below statement:

> "You must have completed a minimum three-year program in computer science,
> information technology, computer science systems, or a related discipline in integrated multimedia or computing science."

**Are they two independent clause:**

```
You must have completed a minimum three-year program in computer science,
information technology, computer science systems. 
Or
You must have completed a related discipline in integrated multimedia or computing
science.
```

**Or they are dependent Clause**

```
You must have completed a minimum three-year program in computer science, 
information technology, computer science systems.
Or
You must have completed a minimum three-year program in a related discipline in
integrated multimedia or computing science.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, "clause" is a countable noun.

> Are they two independent clauses?

No.

> Or they are dependent clauses?"

No.

You must have completed a minimum three-year program

(i) **in** computer science,

(ii) (in) information technology,

(iii) (in) computer science systems, **or**

(iv) (in) a related discipline in integrated multimedia or computing science."

All of them are adjectival modifiers modifying "program".

"Or" is a coordinating conjunction that, in this case joins phrases of equal value.

The comma after "or", in the example is an "Oxford comma" it is not necessary in all cases, and is not necessary in this - it is optional.